# Control not entering into PHP class file

Tags: php, mysql, class

I'm calling a class that does not seem to be executing any of its methods. Consider the following file (db-com.php):

```
echo "entered db-com.php";
class DBCom {
    /**
     * @var string Holds the query string.
     * If the blank constructor is used, make sure to use the parametrized functions.
     */
    var $queryString;

    /**
     * @var resource Holds the MySQL Resource returned by mysql_query function
     */
    var $queryResult;

    /**
     * @var array Holds the entire array of the result.
     */
    var $queryArray;

    function __construct() {
        $this->queryString = $this->queryResult = $this->queryArray = '';
    }
    function __construct($qS) {
        $this->queryString = $qS;
        $this->queryResult = mysql_query($this->queryString);
        $this->queryArray = '';
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return array An array containing all the elements of the requested query.
     */
    function get_query_array() {
        if($this->queryString == '' || $this->queryString == "") {
            die("Query String is Empty. Cannot Proceed.");
        }
        for ( $i = 0 ; $fetchedArray = mysql_fetch_array( $this->queryResult ) ; $i++) {
            $this->queryArray[$i] = $fetchedArray;
        }
        return $this->queryArray;
    }
}
```

When in another file I write:

```
require ( 'some_path/db-com.php' );
```

it doesn't even enter this file. i.e. even the first `echo` statement doesn't get displayed.

This is not happening with any other class files. Only this type of class involving SQL functions. So I even started a clean blank file, tested first that control enters it or not (it did) and then wrote all of this, saved it under a different name, and included it, and again this mysterious error popped out.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You don't need to make this community wiki.

Comment: @zack thats the problem, nothing is coming, control doesn't enter the file :)
@kev i just make every one of them a wiki unless required otherwise. helps sometimes. :)

Comment: sorry to be picky but any chance you could rename this so that it's a question and one that reflects the problem

Comment: if you say so!
although i got the answer so won't really matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `__construct()` methods. You can't overload methods like that in PHP.

You probably have `display_error`s turned off, so that is why you can't see the error message:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare
>   DBCom::__construct() in
>   C:\test.php on line 23

Comment: lol thanks!
removing the extra constructor worked!

so do i use default parameters as well to achieve a pseudo overloading?

Comment: you could do, or you could take an associative array as a parameter and then work out what to do based on what keys it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing `<?php ?>`

Comment: yes
i excluded that cause it was causing display problems in this question page

Answer (score 0):

**Sanity check:** Do you have another file on the path that's empty or otherwise outdated?